# Excel: sum using OR criteria using Index / Match formula

Tags: excel, indexing, sum, match, sumifs

I want to use a formula to give me the sum of the numbers in the matrix below for a particular letter for a combination of several months, e.g. What is the sum for row E for the months of May, Jun and Jul?

I'm trying to use a formula like: 
`=SUM(INDEX(B2:M11,MATCH("E",A2:A11,0),MATCH({"May","Jun","Jul"},B1:M1,0)))`
but not having much luck.

```
   Jan  Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
A   11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22
B   21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32
D   31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42
E   41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52
F   51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62
G   61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
H   71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82
I   81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92
J   91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99  100 101 102
K   101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps best is:

`=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A11="E")*ISNUMBER(MATCH(B1:M1,{"May","Jun","Jul"},0))*B2:M11)`

though you can also continue to use `INDEX`/`MATCH` with a small amendment:

`=SUM(INDEX(B2:M11,MATCH("E",A2:A11,0),N(IF(1,MATCH({"May","Jun","Jul"},B1:M1,0)))))`

(*http://excelxor.com/2014/09/05/index-returning-an-array-of-values/*)

Note that, were you to instead use a range of worksheet cells in which to store your month criteria (as opposed to them being hard-coded within the formula, as here), `SUMPRODUCT` would be required in the latter in place of `SUM`.

Regards